# Could we say "I went overseas when I went from Norway to Sweden"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In a [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/overseas_2)

> **overseas** (adv): to or in a foreign country, especially those **separated from your country by the sea or ocean**
>
> to live/work/go overseas
>
> The product is sold both at home and overseas.
>
> He was working overseas for an oil company.

There is no sea between Norway & Sweden.

So, Could we say "**I went overseas when I went from Norway to Sweden**"?

or "go abroad & go overseas" are almost the the same & it doesn't matter whether we have to fly over a sea or not?

Comment: An unrelated opinion: What do you mean by "I went from Norway to Sweden" part? Considering this part, the whole sentence sounds strange to my learner ears.

Comment: You could just say you traveled from Norway to sweden. Many people probably wouldnt notice that it is technically wrong, but as you mention, there is no ocean between

Comment: **overseas**  refers to a land across the ocean as a location or destination, not to the act of traversing the ocean. If we say *Tom is overseas now* we mean Tom is in a foreign land across the water, not that Tom is in a boat on the water or in a plane above the water.

Comment: If a person from New York goes to Canada, we would not say that they were overseas.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, From you answer, I, at first, understood that one could say "I went overseas." if they went from Norway to Sweden. But then I saw that you said "...land across the ocean." So, I got confused, because there is no ocean between "Norway and Sweden". Can they still say "I went overseas."?

Comment: "I went overseas" means "I went to a land on the other side of the ocean".  If someone living in the US says "I went overseas" the meaning is I went to a land that is on the other side of the Atlantic Ocean or on the other side of the Pacific Ocean. It doesn't refer to Mexico or Canada and many people in the US wouldn't use it to refer to South America either.